# How can I get a continuous reading of CPU temperature for Linux based operating systems using Python?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, temperature

I'm trying to make a program for raspberry pi, but I'm continuously switching between Mac and Raspberry Pi. Is there a way to access CPU Temp through Linux using Python. And can I make it work with `tkinter`? (`tkinter` being unable to properly use `while` loops from my knowledge

````py
# How can I get a continuous CPU temperature reading for Linux (Mac//Raspberry Pi) using a 
def function():
    #stuff
    tkinterFrame.after(delay, function)
# im using tkinter so avoiding while loops
# need to use function .after()```

I expect a continuous output that refreshes every second.
````

Comment: you can use multithreading with while loop

Comment: Use file read and `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid multithreading. People suggested that for another section of this GUI I'm building. I found another way to get it done. Multithreading is a skill that I want to with after I finish this piece. Thank you tho. (:

Comment: @Kampi not sure how to do that? 

Comment: This code should work, assuming `delay` is set to 1000 and you've properly set up your tkinter GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Linux gives you the current temperature of the CPU when you read the file `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`. You will get a single line of text with the temperature as an *Integer*. So you have to divide the result by `1000` to get the temperature in `°C`. Please take a look at this simple example which read the current time and the temperature to print both in the terminal.

```
import time
import datetime

while(True):
    CurrentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

    with open(r"/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp") as File:
        CurrentTemp = File.readline()

    print(str(CurrentTime) + " - " + str(float(CurrentTemp) / 1000))

    time.sleep(1)
```

All you have to do now is to store the results and print them (maybe with a plot?). You can use an extra thread to do it, so your application won´t be stuck when you use some kind of delay (because you don´t need to read the temperature every millisecond - every second is enough I think).